# C: Zlib compress not working

Tags: c, zlib

I'm trying a very simple thing: read a minimal text file and compress it with the `compress()` utility from zlib. I think I've done everything fine, I allocate filesize * 10 for the output, it should be more that enough, but I keep getting -5 (Z_BUF_ERROR) as result of the operation.
Any help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "zlib.h"

#define FILE_TO_OPEN "text.txt"

static char* readcontent(const char *filename, int* size)
{
    char* fcontent = NULL;
    int fsize = 0;
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(fp) {
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        fsize = ftell(fp);
        rewind(fp);

        fcontent = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * fsize);
        fread(fcontent, 1, fsize, fp);

        fclose(fp);
    }

    *size = fsize;
    return fcontent;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int input_size;
    char* content_of_file = readcontent(FILE_TO_OPEN, &input_size);

    printf("%d\n", input_size);

    uLongf compressed_data_size;
    char* compressed_data = malloc(sizeof(char) * (input_size * 10));

    int result = compress((Bytef*) compressed_data, (uLongf*)&compressed_data_size, (const Bytef*)content_of_file, (uLongf)input_size);
    printf("%d\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try setting `compressed_data_size` to some meaningful value; also I'd put `rb` in fopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
uLongf compressed_data_size = compressBound(input_size);
```

`compressBound` should be available in `zlib`.

Also you are better of probably using `rb` in `fopen` like I mentioned in my comment before.

Comment: It works, thanks. Can you explain to me the meaning of those numbers 1.001 and 12? Thank you very much

Comment: @pistacchio:seems that's how the destlen is calculated; https://wiki.csc.calpoly.edu/491W11-HRI/browser/Examples/my_erratic/erratic_robot/player/build/player-svn/replace/compressBound.c?rev=3.  I encountered that function on some of their sample pages

Comment: @MarkAdler:Check the link in my above comments, it says it might not always be available there, but if there is one, OP could use that one.

Comment: It's been there since 1.2.0.  All of the deployed zlib's I've seen are between 1.2.3 and 1.2.8.

Comment: @Giorgi: you are arguing with one of the authors of zlib.

Comment: @ninjalj: yeah I realized a bit later :). Well OP is free to use other answer, or Mark could tell me what corrections to put in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Use `fopen(filename, "rb")`.  If you are on Windows that `b` is important to avoid corruption of binary data.

Use [`compressBound()`](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/compress.c#L75) in zlib instead of `input_size * 10` and set `compressed_data_size` before calling `compress()`.  (You do not need to and should not write your own `compressBound()`.)